# MongoServerError trying to join two different conditions

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to execute a MongoDB query using Javascript. More in detail, I want to return documents based on two different conditions.

The first one is shown here:

```
        $or: [
          { "users.username": user.username },
          { buyer: user.username }
        ]
```

The second one is:

```
$or: [
          { description: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { buyer: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { category: { $regex: req.query.q } }
        ]
```

Joining the two conditions in a single query, the one that I have is the following:

```
const expenses = await db
    .collection("expenses")
    .find({
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          { "users.username": user.username },
          { buyer: user.username }
        ]
      },
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          { description: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { buyer: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { category: { $regex: req.query.q } }
        ],
      },
    })
```

When I execute it, I obtain the following error:

```
MongoServerError: Unrecognized expression '$regex'
```

What can I do to solve the error?
Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: idk something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/mZZPQJAuWPQ ?

Comment: are you trying to do and query

Comment: @cmgchess it works the way you proposed, thanks

Comment: you can write an answer if u want

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are conflating the mongo query language with the aggregation pipeline operators.  There is also a Javascript object building error.

##### MQL vs Aggregation pipeline operators

The purpose of the [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#-expr) operator (quoted from the docs):

> Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.

$expr is not just a subgrouping of query operators, it introduces and entirely new set of operators.

Some examples:

- The [$eq](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#-eq) operator can only be used within $expr.
- References to the value of another field (using `$`) can only be used inside $expr
- Many operators behave differently as aggregation operators than query operators, such as [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#-in) vs [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#-in--aggregation-)

The mongo query language has a [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#-regex) operator, but there is no such aggregation pipeline operator.

Aggregation uses `$regexFind`, `$regexMatch`, and `$regexFindAll`, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation

##### Javascript object construction

The first argument to the `find` method is a javascript object.  You are passing:

```
    {
      $expr: {$or: [
          { "users.username": user.username },
          { buyer: user.username }
      ]},
      $expr: {$or: [
          { description: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { buyer: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { category: { $regex: req.query.q } }
      ]}
    }
```

Note that this object has 2 fields with exactly the same name, '$expr'.  While that is technically allowed in BSON, Javascript/JSON do not permit that, so the second definition of the same field name will overwrite the first.
This makes the query being passed:

```
    {
      $expr: {$or: [
          { description: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { buyer: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { category: { $regex: req.query.q } }
      ]}
    }
```

When you need to include several `$or` operators, you will need to combine them using a top level operator, like:

```
{$and: [
      {$or: [
          { "users.username": user.username },
          { buyer: user.username }
      ]},
      {$or: [
          { description: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { buyer: { $regex: req.query.q } },
          { category: { $regex: req.query.q } }
      ]}
]}
```